# I'm getting NoMethodError: undefined method `user' when I run an RSpec test on one of my methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I'm new to programming, and have been learning Ruby on Rails for about 10 weeks now.

When I run an rspec test on the below model, I keep getting

```
NoMethodError:
   undefined method `user' for #<Item:0xab6623c>
```

Here is the model:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :list

  default_scope { where("items.created_at > 7.days.ago") }

  validates :body, length: { minimum: 5 }, presence: true
  validates :user, presence: true
 end
```

Now, I know that the model validates for a user, but I have created a user with Factory Girl and have included it in my spec. 
Here are my factories:

```
FactoryGirl.define do 
  factory :item do 
    body 'item body'
    list 
    user
   end
 end
```

the user factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name "John Fahey"
    sequence(:email, 100) { |n| "person#{n}@example.com" }
    password "helloworld"
    password_confirmation "helloworld"
    confirmed_at Time.now
  end
end
```

...and here is my spec:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe Item do 
  describe "validations" do
    describe "length validation" do

      before do
        user = create(:user)
        item = create(:item, user: user)
      end

      it "only allows items with 5 or more characters." do
        i = item.body(length: 4)
        expect(i.valid?).to eq(false)

        i = item.body(length: 6)
        expect(i.valid?).to eq(true)
    end
   end
  end
 end
```

I read the factory girl "getting started" guide to make sure my syntax was ok when creating the user and item, but I'm not sure why the test isn' recognizing a user. What am I mssing here?

Comment: i think you missing `belongs_to :user` in `Item` model.

Comment: class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :list
  has_many :items, through: :list

end

Comment: I might not be using "has many through" correctly. In the user model, i stated that the user has many items through the list model: class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :list
  has_many :items, through: :list

Comment: As @Зелёный said you need `belongs_to :user` in your *Item* model too.

Comment: ```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :list
  has_many :items, through: :list
  
end
```

Comment: from your `factory_girl` i see you invoke association `user` so i think you missing `belongs_to :user`.

Comment: Thanks guys, that cleared up the problem. Now, just so I don't post a messy comment again, how do you format code for comments?

Comment: @EricLowber between two backtricks `

Comment: i tried markdown syntax ``` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Ok questions answered. Thanks guys.

Comment: @EricLowber just because `belongs_to :user` creates a method with name `user` in the model.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you need to add associations to your models, in order for getter methods like `user` to exist on Item.

So, you probably want to add `has_one :user` to `Item`, and (depending on your needs) `has_many :items` to `User`.

Hope that helps.